# Npgsql and receiving notifications after database restart (PowerShell involved)

Tags: powershell, npgsql

I have PostgreSQL 9.4 that has a table dedicated for a queue of data. I have a trigger to send notification to subscribed clients whenever a new row has been added to the queue. This works fine as long as I do not restart the database, or database host.

On the application side I have a Npgsql connection object that is disposed only when the application shuts down. Npgsql version 3.0.2 is used.

If connection to database disconnects, application keeps running but never re-establishes the connection. To counter this, I added a timer to check whether ConnectionState is Open. But this works only if connection string also includes KeepAlive, otherwise ConnectionState never changes from Open to anything else.

Okay, so now with KeepAlive I can notice if connection is anything but Open, I can then re-open the connection and listen to notifications again. I can now receive notifications again no problem. I also tried KeepAlive without a timer, but it does not re-establish connection by itself.

Now we get to the actual problem. Whenever a notification is received, I obviously need to read and modify the data that was added to queue. For this I use a second connection, leaving original connection to receive notifications.

The second connection opens without any issues, but as soon as I run the first Npgsql ExecuteReader, following exception occurs:
Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

This second connection is always disposed after processing of the new rows are complete, and the second connection was not open when database was restarted.

Anybody have any tips?

(For PowerShell part, see comments.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's probably happening...

Since you're using connection pooling, when you open your second connection you're not actually opening a new physical connection to PostgreSQL, but rather getting a an old connection from the pool. Since you've just had a database restart, that old connection has been broken, and so you get `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. ADO.NET in general doesn't guarantee that a connection returned from the pool is still open, because of performance reasons.

Dealing with database restarts isn't easy. Depending on what exactly you're doing in your application, it may be enough to simply call `NpgsqlConnection.ClearAllPools()` after your keepalive connection detects the restart. In other words, you use the keepalive connection for detecting the restart, and clear the pool once that happens.

If, however, there are other database operations going on in parallel to all this this solution may not be enough, and you may need to catch the exception and retry connecting, etc.

Comment: I tried ClearAllPools, but once database is back up, I am getting following exceptions when trying to re-open connection:
`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:5432`

I tried ClearAllPools without re-opening the connection, but the connection never receives any notifications afterwards.

Comment: If you're getting a connection refused, that means your database isn't back up yet (could be in progress). You may catch that specific exception and and implement a retry loop until the DB is up. In any case you must reopen the connection upon receiving the event that the database is down, otherwise you're using a broken connection object.

Comment: The database is indeed back up, because I can access it just fine at that point. Waiting however long for the connection to recover does not help.

Comment: If you're getting a connection refused while trying to open a connection, that means that nobody's listening on port 5432 (yet). Most likely you have a race condition and need to wait a little bit more time before attempting to connect...

Comment: The database is back and listening just fine. Restarting the client application fixes the problem right away, waiting does not.

Comment: I don't exactly what's going on with your app... As a test, can you try to establish a raw socket connection with Socket.Connect() instead of opening a new NpgsqlConnection? If Socket.Connect() works and NpgsqlConnection.Open() doesn't, that's proof that something is wrong with Npgsql. If not, it's proof that the server isn't listening at localhost:5432...

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply. I've been working on other stuff. I got back to this problem and somehow the connection appears to be working now as expected. In addition to having persistent notification connection, I also have persistent PowerShell instance. Strangely enough after database connection is disrupted, so is the PowerShell instance, giving "The state of the current PowerShell instance is not valid for this operation." exceptions. The notification connection and the PowerShell instance aren't aware of each other in any way, so I don't know why this happens.

Comment: I've worked around the PowerShell issue by making the PowerShell instance temporary, disposing it after work is done. But this is not ideal as time is lost on re-establishing remote connections when next notification arrives.

Comment: You haven't described how PowerShell relates to your .NET process and the database connections so it's difficult to understand what your setup is like...

Comment: Relation is basically as follows: Persistent Npgsql connection receives events. When event is received, it fires up a function that in turn runs many PowerShell scripts and cmdlets in PowerShell instance. The only relation the two had was that they were declared in same scope.

Comment: OK. I suggest trying the Socket.Connect() test above to isolate the issue.